# How to restart a JFrame when creating a multiple level game?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame, restart

I have a one level computer game that I created , and I want to add another level .

Here is the Main :

```
public class Main extends JDialog
{   

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected static TimerThread timerThread;
    static JStatusBar statusBar = new JStatusBar();
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static final int FRAME_LOCATION_X = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_LOCATION_Y = 50;
    private static final int FRAME_SIZE_X = 850; // animator's target frames per second
    private static final int FRAME_SIZE_Y = 700; // animator's target frames per second
    private static final String WorldName = "FPS 2013 CG Project";
    private static final String HARD_TARGET = "src/res/target.jpg";
    private static final String runningOut = "Time is running out - you have : ";

    static int interval;
    static Timer timer1;
    static JLabel changingLabel1 = null;


    /**
     *  NEW
     */

    private static Timer timer;
    private static int count = 60;

    private static ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            count--;
            if (count == 0)
                timer.stop();
            changingLabel1.setText(runningOut + count + " seconds"); 
        }
    };


    public static void exitProcedure() {
        timerThread.setRunning(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }


        /**
         * Clock timer1 
         * @author X2
         *
         */
        public static class TimerThread extends Thread 
        {

            protected boolean isRunning;

            protected JLabel dateLabel;
            protected JLabel timeLabel;

            protected SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = 
                    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
            protected SimpleDateFormat timeFormat =
                    new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

            public TimerThread(JLabel dateLabel, JLabel timeLabel) {
                this.dateLabel = dateLabel;
                this.timeLabel = timeLabel;
                this.isRunning = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (isRunning) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            Date currentTime = currentCalendar.getTime();
                            dateLabel.setText(dateFormat.format(currentTime));
                            timeLabel.setText(timeFormat.format(currentTime));
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
                this.isRunning = isRunning;
            }

        }




    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {

                    frame = new JFrame(WorldName);

                    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
                    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                    /**
                     *  the timer of the count-down
                     */

                    timer = new Timer(1000, timerAction);
                    timer.start();

                    changingLabel1 = new JLabel(runningOut);
                    statusBar.setLeftComponent(changingLabel1);

                    final JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel();
                    dateLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    statusBar.addRightComponent(dateLabel);

                    final JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
                    timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    statusBar.addRightComponent(timeLabel);

                    contentPane.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                            exitProcedure();
                        }
                    });

                    timerThread = new TimerThread(dateLabel, timeLabel);
                    timerThread.start();

                    Renderer myCanvas = new Renderer();
                    final Animator animator = new Animator(myCanvas);

                    Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                    BufferedImage originalImage = null;

                    try 
                    {
                        originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(HARD_TARGET));
                    } 

                    catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
                    Cursor newCursor = t.createCustomCursor(originalImage, new Point(0, 0), "none"); 

                    frame.setCursor(newCursor);
                    frame.setLocation(FRAME_LOCATION_X, FRAME_LOCATION_Y);
                    frame.add(myCanvas);
                    frame.setSize(FRAME_SIZE_X, FRAME_SIZE_Y);
                    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()

                    {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                        {
                            new Thread() 
                            {
                                 @Override
                                 public void run() 
                                 {
                                     animator.stop();
                                     System.exit(0);
                                 }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });

                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    animator.start();
                    myCanvas.requestFocus();
                    myCanvas.setFocusable(true);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

This Main function uses the class Renderer , i.e.

```
class Renderer extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener, KeyListener ,MouseListener ,MouseMotionListener {...}
```

And that class holds the first level of the game .

As you can see I'm also using `JFrame` and `JOGL 1.0` .

My question is : how can I reset the JFrame after I'm done with the 1st level ? Obviously I can't use `System.exit(0);`  , since it would quit the entire program .

What I want is to move to another class that holds the 2nd level .

How can I do that without exiting with `System.exit(0);` ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just give it a new renderer when you're done with the first level?

Comment: Just a suggestion try using JPanel for each level. When a level is completed you can dispatch some Event to JFrame to change to next level's JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29), you can effectively stop the panel. Then just create a new one `JFrame` and `add()` it. Consider making the `JFrame` creation its own function so you don't have to keep rewriting it if do you this.

Answer (score 1):

well you can use `frame.dispose()` then create the same JFrame with the next level...

I suggest you to restructure your code...your Main class should contain only the main method, and from where you should start the game, which would be located in another class containing the JFrame and Thread...