# Restarting a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a game and I have a Restart-function. I have looked around and found this: [How to restart a JFrame when creating a multiple level game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114622/how-to-restart-a-jframe-when-creating-a-multiple-level-game)
but in my program I extend JFrame so I can't just simply .remove(). Anyone got any idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What is it about your code that prevents you from calling .Remove()? Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: Because when I extend JFrame I don't have this in my code: private static JFrame frame; So I can't simply just use frame.remove(). The comment which got removed who said .dispose() worked. But then I want to restart it again.

Comment: You don't have to use `frame.remove()`. Your class extends `JFrame` so just do `this.remove()` or simply `remove()`.

Comment: I used this.removeAll(); and so the game freezes but all the graphics remain. I want to restart it :/

Comment: Don't extend `JFrame`; update its content.

Comment: See also the reset button handler in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).